# StartService returns error 1053

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-services, system-error

I created a `Windows service` application in `C++` and installed it in my system using `CreateService` and `StartService`. The service was successfully created and started. Now I tried to install the same service in a remote system. I copied the `exe` of my service application to the remote system using `CopyFile` and called `OpenSCManager` and `CreateService` and the service was created in remote system. However  `StartService` always returned `Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.`

I tried to start it as `Localsystem`,`LocalService` and `NetworkService`. But the same error occured. How can I get rid of this..

EDIT:
I also tried aading `ServicesPipeTimeout` entry to registry with value 60000. But the service returned error before the timeout reached :(

Comment: Step 1 is to debug the startup to see where it is failing. Trying to guess what your problem is won't be productive.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan :  On trying to start a service from an executable residing in a remote system, what can I debug? I debugged the program from which I try to strat the service.

Comment: Use trace debugging. Add logging. Find out where execution blocks. There is more to debugging that the IDE's interactive debugger.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Can you please explain how to add logging? I haven't done any logging yet..

Comment: Not in comments I cannot. Try some research.

Comment: Once you've identified the line of code that is hanging (by process of elimination if nothing else) you may wish to post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  One simple approach to identifying the problem spot is to put in a call to ExitProcess, which should make the service startup fail in a different way.  If it fails that way, the call to ExitProcess comes before the problem spot; if you still get 1053, the call to ExitProcess comes after the problem spot.